# What's the best way to check if a non-numeric value is in a range?

Tags: r, algorithm, performance

Sometimes, thinking about the best algorithm is tricky. Well I have to work with some ranges of the form "letter/number/number", for example X86-Z95 would be a range. Actually I need to see if a given code is in the code range. I thought I'd generate an array containing the ranges and check if the code is in the array. But as I had a lot of work to implement the algorithm, I think there is an easier way to implement it. I would like to see some more efficient or elegant solution. I leave my code below.

Thanks in advance!

```
library(stringr)
generateInterval = function(str_interval) {
  limits = strsplit(str_interval, '-')[[1]]
  letters_limits = substr(limits, 1, 1)
  numbers_limits = as.numeric(substr(limits, 2, 3))
  if (letters_limits[1] == letters_limits[2]) {
    interval = paste0(letters_limits[1], numbers_limits[1]:numbers_limits[2])
  } else {
    pos = which(LETTERS %in% letters_limits)
    interval_letters = LETTERS[pos[1]:pos[2]]
    numbers = as.numeric(substr(limits, 2, 3))
    interval = c()
    for (i in 1:length(interval_letters)) {
      if (i == 1) {
        interval = c(interval, paste0(interval_letters[i], numbers[1]:99))
      } else if (i == length(interval_letters)) {
        interval = c(interval, paste0(interval_letters[i], 0:numbers[2]))
      } else {
        interval = c(interval, paste0(interval_letters[i], 0:99))
      }
    } 
  }
  interval = ifelse(str_length(interval) == 2,
                    paste0(substr(interval, 1, 1), 0, substr(interval, 2, 2)),
                    interval)
  
  return(interval)
}

generateInterval('A72-B10')
```

Comment: `data.table::inrange` for instance.

Comment: Maybe, in your case you can treat your range as a number with base 36 and convert to an int using `int(value, 36)`? This will result in an ability to compare them, where letters will go in alphabetical order and the first digits are more important then the last ones.

Comment: Can't you just compare? With the posted limits, `"X86" <= "X92" && "X92" <= "Z95"` returns `TRUE` but `"X86" <= "X85" && "X85" <= "Z95"` returns `FALSE`.

Comment: why the `python` tag?

Comment: Thanks @vladko312, , I would never have thought that I could work with the idea of ​​changing the base. Well thought.

Comment: Thanks  @RuiBarradas, It worked, I hadn't thought of that! I accept as an answer.

Comment: @buran, python is in fashion. Staff respond faster.

Comment: Please, don't abuse tags! Your question has nothing to do with python. And we are not staff. The community consists of volunteers, so people answer when and as quickly as they can, given their circumstances..

Comment: Understood @buran, no intention to treat anyone as an employee. Actually any language would suit me, but as I use R and python more often, I decided to put these tags. Sorry for any offense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Following the [OP's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71079892/whats-the-best-way-to-check-if-a-non-numeric-value-is-in-a-range/71080535#comment125651401_71079892) here is a way in base R. The only thing that needs to be done is to realize that R can compare strings. And the one-line function will check if the codes are within range.

```r
within_range <- function(x, lower, upper) lower <= x & x <= upper

within_range(c("X92", "X84", "A10", "Y30"), lower = "X86", upper = "Z95")
#> [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>